# Using Laravel Raw Query with Placeholder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query in my Model:

Model:

```
 class Webmasters {
      public static function webmasters($filt, $cat) {
         $top_pages = DB::table('web.tools')
                ->where('filter',$filt)
                ->where('category', $cat)
                ->limit(20)->get();
         return $top_pages;
}
```

The variables **$filt** and **$cat** are passed on as parameters from the controller.

I would like to use a Query like this:

```
 class Webmaster {
      public static function webmasters($filt, $cat) {
         $top_pages = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT *
                                         FROM web.tools
                                         WHERE filter = $filt
                                         WHERE category = $cat
                                         LIMIT 20"));
          return $top_pages;
       }
 }
```

I however do not now how to use these placeholders on the second query. The first one works like a charm, but the second one gives me an sql error because of the placeholders **$filt**
and **$cat**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an array of parameters to bind to the select.

```
 class Webmaster {
      public static function webmasters($filt, $cat) {
         $top_pages = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT *
                                         FROM web.tools
                                         WHERE filter = :filter
                                         AND category = :category
                                         LIMIT 20"), [
                                             ':filter' => $filt,
                                             ':category' => $cat
                                         ]);
          return $top_pages;
       }
 }
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but i'm continously getting an SQLSTATE 42601 Error pointing at the where clauses.

Comment: Your original query has 2 WHERE's... you want WHERE filter = :filter AND category = :category.

Comment: Thats it. Sorry for the trivial mistake.