# Limit DB::query on multiple tables in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am running a query on multiple table and i want to limit it to 5 results but it giving me below error.

```
$projects = DB::query("select * from project, project_budget,user 
                    where prj_id=pb_prj_id 
                    and prj_usr_id=usr_id 
                    and prj_status = 'open' 
                    and prj_expiry>'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                    order by prj_updated_date desc")->take(5)->get();
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select * limit 5)

Comment: Don't forget that [Laravel has placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380060/using-laravel-raw-query-with-placeholder) to make what you're doing safer.

Comment: if you need to use `DB::query` then it should be a raw query  so the `limit 5` should be in the `query` as `order by prj_updated_date desc limit 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved by using query builder.

```
$projectExpiry = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$projects =     DB::table('project')
                ->join('project_budget', 'project.prj_id', '=', 'project_budget.pb_prj_id')
                ->join('users', 'project.prj_usr_id', '=', 'users.prj_usr_id')
                ->where('prj_status',  '=' , 'open')
                ->where('prj_expiry',  '<' , $projectExpiry )
                ->orderBy('prj_updated_date',  'desc')
                ->take(5)->get();
```