# get referral users against user id in laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get the users who are referred by a user and all other users who referred by the first user's referral users.

To get this kind of result I am recursive query in mysql and I can get the exact result, the query is:

```
        WITH recursive cte as ( 
select * from users where reff_user = '$id' 
union all 
select t.* from cte c
  join users t 
    on t.reff_user = c.id ) 
select * 
  from cte 
 ORDER 
    BY created_at DESC
```

I want to know that how can I achieve the same result using laravel query.

I have tried the belongsTo and hasMany functions in User modal to get the referal users but the result is empty while with recursive query, I can get all users down to a specific user.

Please give some examples to laravel query that how I can use recursive query in laravel.

-------------------------Post Edit--------------------

I have also tried the raw query:

```
DB::select( DB::raw("WITH recursive cte as (select * from users where reff_user = '$id' union all select t.* from cte c join users t on t.reff_user = c.id) select * from cte ORDER BY created_at DESC") );
```

but got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive cte as (select * from users where reff_user = 1 union all select t.* f' at line 1 (SQL: WITH recursive cte as (select * from users where reff_user = 1 union all select t.* from cte c join users t on t.reff_user = c.id) select * from cte ORDER BY created_at DESC)
```

Comment: Note: Use **placeholder values** for all data, like `$id` here, which has no place being injected in the query.

Comment: @tadman thank brother for the comment, can you please give an example for placeholder values? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: You can always use [raw queries with placeholders using `DB::raw`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380060/using-laravel-raw-query-with-placeholder) in Laravel if you're really stuck. While it's better to try and express this with Eloquent it's not always possible, nor worth the fuss.

Comment: I already tried with raw query, but getting this error. While it is working fine with simple php query. error is: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive cte as (select * from users where reff_user = 1 union all select t.* f' at line 1 (SQL: WITH recursive cte as (select * from users where reff_user = 1 union all select t.* from cte c join users t on t.reff_user = c.id) select * from cte ORDER BY created_at DESC)

Comment: Try and include that as an edit to your question as it's much harder to read as a comment.

Comment: @tadman I already edited the question and sorry for making my previous comment too long. can you just check the question now?

Comment: Just noticed that now. Yeah, that is strange. I thought it might be a MySQL version issue, but perhaps not. The `DB::select` call should be running it as-is, so it should be fine. Maybe a Larvel expert can weigh in.

Comment: i see, ok, lets wait then for an expert laravel developer :) . Till than I am struggling myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a lot about this and after that I did some practicals by uploading the website to another hosting and there I upgraded the mysql version from cpanel and then checked the website and the query works fine than.

```
So the issue was mysql version mismatch as @tadman said in the comment section. Thanks to him.
```