# Laravel testing assertion on MySQL point column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I made an API inserting into MySQL POINT column, and I don't know how to do testing with it.
I am trying `assertDatabaseHas` with `DB::raw(DB::raw("ST_SRID(POINT({$latitude},{$longitude}), 4326)"))` , `DB::raw("(ST_GeomFromText('POINT({latitude} {$longitude}), 4326'))")` , none of them worked, and the latter is the query I use to insert.

Anyone could help will be greatly appreciated.

### UPDATED 2021/4/4

- My migration

```
$table->point('location', 4326)->spatialIndex();
```

- My insert code

```
TestModel::create(['location' => DB::raw(DB::"ST_SRID(Point({$latitude},{$longitude}),4326)")]);
```

- My assertion

```
$response->assertJson(['location' => DB::raw(DB::"ST_SRID(Point({$latitude},{$longitude}),4326)")])
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has SQL injections in it, which can be trivially avoided using [placeholder values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380060/using-laravel-raw-query-with-placeholder).

Comment: Can you explain "none of them worked" in more technical terms? Did you get a specific error?

Comment: First of all, @Ray you do not test you database like that, you test your code logic with Unit test or Feature tests, so you should do a Feature test where you allow the user to save this data, and then retrieve it on your test (after inserted) and using objects (maybe a model) try to read the same exact data you sent, so it got correctly inserted...

Comment: @tadman Yup I know. I've used regular to define `latitude` and `longitude` format, and I think it may prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @tadman Yup the error is assertion failed. It can't find the same data format I assert in the DB

Comment: @matiaslauriti I got what you mean. Because I refresh the database on every testing, I assume that `assertDatabaseHas` would do the great job to make sure my API does the same work as I expect.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Retrieve the data from DB would probably do the job because I may be able to use ST function to get x, y in text form, then I could compare with the data which I make the POST API with. However, I just think it would be a bit more troublesome compared to the logic mentioned above.

Comment: @matiaslauriti My logic is
1. prepare the fake data
2. call the API to store some data including the coordinates mentioned
3. Assert the data has been successfully stored

Comment: @Ray that is correct, you are doing it the right way, could you share your Test code and migration if able ? The more you share the better.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Sorry for my late reply. I've been busy those days. I've updated my post with the migration, insert code, and assertion code. Hope I will be helpful.

Comment: I have never used a `DB::something` in a test... I have no idea what `DB::raw` will do with `assertJson`, you should put a valid string, not a `DB` raw, what do you expect as a `location` response ? If the response is `location: "123,123"`, you should write that not `DB::raw`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yup. I tried string way as well. However, it failed as well. Finally I used latitude and longitude assertion instead of Location column type. I still record location for ST function usage, but also record latitude and longitude for testing assertion. Not sure if it's a good way though.